# Why does only half the background show for sub menu links in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

For modern browsers I am using a CSS gradient on the menu hover-state background.  The gradient filter in IE doesn't look so good, so I will be using a background-image taken from  a screen shot in chrome. 
The problem I am having is that in IE only half of the element background is shown when a sub menu link is hovered, the bottom half is clipped.  Using IE developer tools the  element appears to have the proper height, but only half the background is shown.

```css
.main-navigation li ul li a {
    overflow: visible;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    width: 178px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 3.2em;
    color: #fefefe;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}   

.main-navigation li ul li a:hover {
    background: #dddddd; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%, #545454 2%, #191919 95%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dddddd), color-stop(2%,#545454), color-stop(95%,#191919)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#545454 2%,#191919 95%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#545454 2%,#191919 95%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dddddd 0%,#545454 2%,#191919 95%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dddddd 0%,#545454 2%,#191919 95%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dddddd', endColorstr='#191919',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    background-image: url('img/subhoverbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: You should live a demo on jsfiddle.net and specify which IE are you talking about. Screenshots are nice too.

Comment: not sure how this is a wordpress question, regardless if you are using it on wordpress site or not just for clarification... :)

Comment: Hello all, I agree that screenshots are nice, unfortunately being a newb I couldn't supply them.  I have considered this a WordPress question because I am trying to modify the background appearance of the standard Twenty Twelve Navigation Menu, and it is behaving strangely.  The issue affects all versions of IE, except maybe IE10. I solved the issue by going in another direction with the design, but I would still like to know for future reference if anyone else has experience or advice with this issue, as I tend to use the most recent WP standard theme as a jumping off point.